# How to sign a message with an ECDSA string privateKey

Tags: go, ecdsa

I'm trying to sign a message with an ECDSA `privateKey` but with a type string.
The problem is in order to sign the message I need to use the "Sign" method from the `ecdsa` package.

```
func (priv *PrivateKey) Sign(rand io.Reader, msg []byte, opts crypto.SignerOpts) ([]byte, error)
```

This method can only take a `PrivateKey` type.
How can I convert my string private key to this type? Or is another method available ?

Answer (score 1):

You can parse DER-encoded elliptic curve private keys using the standard library's [x509.ParseECPrivateKey](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParseECPrivateKey).

```
derKey := []byte(keyString)
privKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(derKey)
if err != nil {
  panic(err)
}
signedMsg, err := privKey.Sign(randReader, msg, otps)
```

If your key is in PEM format, you must first decode it using [pem.Decode](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/#Decode):

```
var block *pem.Block
if block, _ = pem.Decode([]byte(keyString)); block == nil {
    panic("expected pem block")
}
privKey, err := x509.ParseECPrivateKey(block.Bytes)
// etc... the rest is the same
```